# Best way to check postgres data changes

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a C++ application that needs to read user data stored in a database. This data can be changed anytime by the user (but wont change much). I'd rather the code not look up data every time it runs but read all data once from the database, and only re-read it if anything changes. The piece of code does not run all the time so I don't need real time notifications, it only needs to know if data changed from last read when it goes to run.

The problem is what is the best way to check for data changes? I thought about using notify, but I can't poll and I can't tell if polling isn't necessary. I thought about a time stamp, but that seems unreliable and I'm not sure if I will have a weird problem in different time zones? Maybe shared memory, but then why not just use a file and time stamp (its not a lot of data)?

Anyone with experience in this have any good suggestions?

Thanks